# Can i extend graphql fragments?

Tags: graphql

For example, i have the next query for the paragraph:

```
query ParagraphText {
  field_title
  field_body
  field_subtitle
  field_image
  field_button
}
```

And i use this paragraph on the front page. But also i use this paragraph on another page but i dont want this query to have button.
Is there an opportunity to extend fragment?

```
fragment ParagraphText on paragraph__text {
  field_title
  field_body
  field_subtitle
  field_image
}

fragment ParagraphTextWithButton extends ParagraphText {
  field_button
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can expand a fragment in a fragment definition to do this:

```
fragment ParagraphText on paragraph__text {
  field_title
  field_body
  field_subtitle
  field_image
}

fragment ParagraphTextWithButton on paragraph__text {
  ...ParagraphText
  field_button
}
```